# How to invoke the explicitly interface implement method while the interface is private/internal?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, invoke

I want to invoke the method `ICompiledQuery IProvider.Compile(Expression query)` defined in `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider` class.

But the `IProvider` interface is internal, so I can not do the cast. Is there any way to invoke the method?

Comment: Use reflection. Why would you want this btw?

Comment: [XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062646/calling-an-function-inside-an-internal-class-from-an-another-executable

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I don't think reflection will work, eg: I can get the instance of SqlProvider(who implements IProvider), execute instance.GetType().GetMembers(), you can not see the Compile MethodInfo.

Comment: No, you have to get the members of the interface.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: What I want to do is get the sql datacommand text generated by the SqlProvider, without actually execute the sql

Comment: @PatrickHofman, the interface is internal, and how can I can the type of the interface

Comment: Get it from the `Assembly`. See `Assembly.GetTypes`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Then, how can I invoke the Compile method implemented by SqlProvider?I try the followings: `var t = typeof(SqlProvider).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(n=>n.Name.Contains("IProvider")).First();
 t.InvokeMember("Compile", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, provider, new object[] { q.Expression });` System.MissingMethodException throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the method and invoke it.

```
// Some test stuff, replace this with your own.
Expression e = null;
SqlProvider p = new SqlProvider();

// Get the IProvider interface
var iProvider = typeof(SqlProvider).FindInterfaces((t, o) => t.FullName == "System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider", null).FirstOrDefault();

if (iProvider != null)
{
    // Get the Compile method on the interface
    MethodInfo m = iProvider.GetMethod("Compile");

    // Call it!
    var output = m.Invoke(p, new object[] { e });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you code works. I wrongly thought DataQuery<>.Provider is a SqlProvider previously and use it to call GetInterfaces(), no IProvider found.